# How do I populate an empty array, with a specific table in another sheet, based on dropdown menu?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

### How can I populate an array, with a specific financials table from another sheet, depending on the chosen company in the dropdown list?

**SO...** populate the blue-area in **DASHBOARD!**, with the blue-area in **FINANCIALS!**, because it matches the company in the dropdown menu on **DASHBOARD!**.

Or is there an easier way to do this. **In essence...** I want the chosen company's key financials to be shown, when it is chosen in the dropdown menu...

Thank you so much in advance!

[GOOGLE SHEETS LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_zuurcMeezNjVqZqqa9BhV-6x6H6bgeZoFbJeqwhVM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [‘QUERY’](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function.

In the “FINANCIALS” sheet - Column A , I added the name of the company (you can hide this column if you prefer). This way we can make a query and return only rows that match with that specific company.

[image]


In the “DASHBOARD” sheet, cell D15, I added the following:

```
=QUERY(FINANCIALS!A6:H42,"select C,D,E,F,G,H where A='"&B10&"'",0)
```

And after formatting the rows with Number/Percent, this is the result which matches with the information in the "FINANCIALS" sheet:
[image]